# Как решить задачу на oracle sql без создания промежуточных таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

Как решить задачу на oracle sql без создания промежуточных таблицы, условие ниже.

Есть неограниченное количество монет номиналом 2, 5, 7 рублей.
Нужно собрать из них 100 рублей всеми возможными способами.
Каждая монетка используется хотя бы один раз

Пытался через with as и connect by решить, не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with rec(a,b,c) as
(select 2 a, 5 b, 7 c from dual
union all
select a+2,b+5,c+7 from rec
where a<=100 or b <=100 or c <=100
)
select r1.a/2 "2",r2.b/5 "5",r3.c/7 "7", r1.a+r2.b+r3.c z from rec r1,rec r2,rec r3
where r1.a+r2.b+r3.c =100
;
```